# SPSS tables to latex (PDF) without creating an A4 page

Tags: pdf, spss

This may be a stupid question, but I can't figure it out.
I have made some tables in SPSS. Now I want them over to my latex document.

What I do, it that I right-click the table in SPSS, and press export.
Here I can choose between PDF or .doc. BUT the PDF-file created, generates a file with the table on top of a page (A4 size, with "page 1" at the bottom). I do not want this, I only want the table.
example how it turns out:
[image: How it turns out, I do not want this]

Example how I want it to turn out:
[image: I want it like this]

If I export to word, I can further save as PDF, but same problem occurs.

Screenshot works, but does not give me the same picture-quality that I prefer.

Do anyone of you have any tips for me?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately SPSS does not provide native table export to Latex. It does provide table export to html and xls, which can post-hoc be converted to Tex tables. PDF output for everything forces to export the full page (very annoying for graphics as well) - but you probably don't want to insert the image of the table (you could crop the PDF if need be), but have a Tex table (in the same font) as your document anyway.

One thing I have done in the past to make the export to text tables with specific markup is to use the `PRINT` or `LIST` commands to print the text table to the output (or to a text file) that is closer to the end goal. In [this NABBLE post](http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/Accessing-a-local-macro-value-in-an-outside-macro-td5723922.html#a5723962) I have some syntax that makes pandoc flavored pipe style markdown tables - it should be pretty clear how that same approach could be used for Tex tables (actually Tex tables should be much simpler).

Here is an example of some code using `LIST` to make a the markup closer to Tex tables.

```
DATA LIST FREE / Variable (A1) Mean Median (2F4.2).
BEGIN DATA
A 3.25 2.00
B 2.56 2.50
C 9.87 10.20
END DATA.

*Using LIST to make Latex style table.
STRING Mid (A1) End (A2).
COMPUTE Mid = "&".
COMPUTE End = "//".
LIST /VARIABLES = Variable Mid Mean Mid Median End.
```

And here is a screen shot of the produced output on my machine.

[image]

So here I would still have to copy-paste the text output into my Tex document, (and make the header row).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use OMS to save designed items in a variety of formats, including XML and then use an xml-to-Latex tool such as xmltex.  You could probably even generate such a conversion with XSLT from the XML.

From the Viewer, you could also retrieve the table with Python scripting and use a Python-based converter tool.